# Q.nfcall or Q.denodeify for constructors

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I'm using a library providing a class whose constructor makes use of the Node.js callback pattern:

```
new FooBar({key: value}, function(err, data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I want to use a promise instead so that I can do something like this:

```
fooBarWrapper({key: value}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I know I can create a wrapper with `Q.denodeify` or call a function with `Q.nfcall`, but how does it work for constructors?

Comment: Constructors cannot return objects asynchronously. So, the constructor might be storing the callback function passed in it and invokes it whenever a particular event occurs.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing your usage case for the constructor.

Comment: I actually don't want to use the constructed object. I just need to call the constructor like any other static function.

Comment: Then you probably don't need a constructor, just a regular function called without `new`.

Comment: The library that I use does not provide another entry point. It's node-exif.

Comment: related: [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398699/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors shouldn't make asynchronous calls. This is not fun to do because the person making this library are performing async IO in constructors which is totally not cool of them :)

I suggest you wrap that function in a callback:

```
function fooBar(val, cb){
    new FooBar(val, cb);
}
```

Which would let you call `Q.nfcall` or `Q.denodeify` from your code. I believe this is better than creating an explicit deferred.

Comment: I totally agree. It's just not cool! :-) Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it myself. You can use `Q.defer` to convert the callback to a promise:

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
new FooBar({key: value}, deferred.makeNodeResolver());
deferred.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I'm leaving this answer here in the hope that it helps anybody else having the same problem.